# CSS/SCSS disappear on routerLink route change

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-routing, angular-components

CSS/SCSS is not being applied to the component when visiting compoment/route for the second time. `"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",`

Goal: CSS to be applied to the component every time the user visits the route/component not only the first time.

> 1. Going into a route "/dashboard/171/table" via primeng menu routerLink button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjLVa.png

> 2. Going into a route /dashboard/171

> 3. Going back into a route "/dashboard/171/table" via primeng menu routerLink button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvBWU.png

app.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

dashboard-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'new-world', component: NewWorldComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id', loadChildren: () => import('./world/world.module').then(m => m.WorldModule),
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

world-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WorldComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: NewWorldComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'table', component: UserDataTableComponent, resolve: {
          players: UserDataAllyPlayersResolver,
          villages: UserDataAllyVillagesResolver,
          tribes: UserDataAllyTribesResolver
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'enemy-towers', component: NewWorldComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

user-data-table.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TableModule,
    CommonModule,
    ButtonModule,
    RippleModule,
    ProgressSpinnerModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SidebarModule,
    SliderModule
  ],
  exports: [
    UserDataTableComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserDataTableComponent,
  ]
})
export class UserDataTableModule {
}
```

user-data-table.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'pl-user-data-table',
  templateUrl: './user-data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-data-table.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

user-data-table.component.scss

```css
pl-user-data-table {
  p-table #pr_id_1-table {
    thead > tr {
      th {
        font-size: 9px;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      th:nth-child(1) {
        width: 6%;
      }

      th:nth-child(2) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      th:nth-child(3) {
        width: 6%;

      }

      th:nth-child(4) {
        width: 18%;

      }

      th:nth-child(5) {
        width: 6%;
      }

      th:nth-child(6) {
        width: 6%;

      }

      th:nth-child(7) {
        width: 8%;
      }

      th:nth-child(8) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      th:nth-child(9) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      th:nth-child(10) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      th:nth-child(11) {
        width: 10%;

      }

    }
    tbody > tr {
      td {
        font-size: 11px;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      td:nth-child(1) {
        width: 6%;
      }

      td:nth-child(2) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      td:nth-child(3) {
        width: 6%;

      }

      td:nth-child(4) {
        width: 18%;

      }

      td:nth-child(5) {
        width: 6%;
      }

      td:nth-child(6) {
        width: 6%;

      }

      td:nth-child(7) {
        width: 8%;
      }

      td:nth-child(8) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      td:nth-child(9) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      td:nth-child(10) {
        width: 10%;

      }

      td:nth-child(11) {
        width: 10%;

      }

    }
  }
  .top-bar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .user-data-table-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    .custom-side-button{
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace routerLink/[routerLink] with href, it will reload the page and css will be applied.
My best guess is that we are injecting content dynamically with help of css which is not applying the css whereas If we use href then it reloads and instead of changing the Exisitng DOM it reloads it.

If you have any other solution , Please let us know.